# leetcode 88. Merge Sorted Array c++ runtime error

Tags: c++, mergesort

I am doing leetcode problem 88. Here is the link: [Merge Sorted Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-sorted-array/).

Given two sorted integer arrays nums1 and nums2, merge nums2 into nums1 as one sorted array. The number of elements initialized in nums1 and nums2 are m and n respectively. You may assume that nums1 has enough space (size that is greater or equal to m + n) to hold additional elements from nums2.

I use c++ to solve this problem. But I always got runtime error like this:

```
Runtime Error Message:
Line 922: Char 34: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type' (stl_vector.h)
Last executed input:
[1]
1
[]
0
```

Here is my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void merge(vector<int>& nums1, int m, vector<int>& nums2, int n) {
        int output[m+n] = {0};
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        if(sizeof(nums1) == 0)
        {
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                nums1[i] = nums2[i];
            }
            return;
        }
        if(sizeof(nums2) == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        for(int k = 0; k < m+n; k++)
        {
            if(nums1[i] <= nums2[j])
            {
                if(i < m)
                {
                    output[k] = nums1[i];
                    i++; 
                }
                else if(j < n)
                {
                    output[k] = nums2[j];
                    j++;
                }
            }
            else if(nums1[i] >= nums2[j])
            {
                if(j < n)
                {
                    output[k] = nums2[j];
                    j++;
                }
                else if(i < m)
                {
                    output[k] = nums1[i];
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < m+n; i++)
        {
            nums1[i] = output[i];
        }
    }
};
```

It's easy to test, just click the link above and copy my code then submit it. I hope someone could help me.

Comment: `sizeof(nums1) == 0` is never true. Neither is `sizeof(nums2) == 0`

Comment: Note that you don't need an additionalp array. The question suggests not to do it (num1 large enough). Try filling num1 by the end first

Comment: You must test validity of `i` and `j` before using `num1[i]` and `num2[j]`.  UB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some flaws in your current approach, like:

- `sizeof(nums1)` operator will only give you `0` in case: `nums1[],m=0,nums2[],n=0`, because for all other cases when `m=0` but `n!=0`, `nums1` will contain `0`'s and it won't be an empty list. Ex. `nums1[0,0],m=0,nums2[1,2],n=2`. To handle this, check if `m==0` or `n==0` instead of using `sizeof`.
- In line `if(nums1[i] <= nums2[j])`, if `j>=n`, it will throw a segmentation error.
- You may find more flaws if you check all test cases on LeetCode.

A correct approach is given below. This solution is accepted on LeetCode. I've added comments which are mostly self-explanatory. Feel free to comment if you have any queries.

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    void merge(vector<int>& nums1, int m, vector<int>& nums2, int n) {
        int output[m+n] = {0};
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        if(m == 0) // nums1 is empty. Ex. nums1[0,0],m=0 and nums2[1,2],n=2
        {
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                nums1[i] = nums2[i];
            }
            return;
        }
        if(n == 0) // nums2 is empty. Ex. nums1[1,2],m=2 and nums2[],n=0
        {
            return;
        }
        for(k = 0; k < m+n; k++)
        {
            if(i>=m || j>=n) // Check if we've exhausted any of nums1 or nums2 list
                break;
            if(nums1[i] <= nums2[j]) // if nums1[i] <= nums2[j]
            {
                output[k] = nums1[i];
                i++;
            }
            else{ // else, nums1[i] > nums2[j]
                output[k] = nums2[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
        while(i<m){ // If some elements are left in nums1. Ex: nums1[4,0,0],m=1 and nums2[1,2],n=2
            output[k] = nums1[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        while(j<n){ // If some elements are left in nums2. Ex: nums1[1,2,0],m=2 and nums2[4],n=1
            output[k] = nums2[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < m+n; i++) // Copy back to nums1
        {
            nums1[i] = output[i];
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `std::vector`, to check if it's empty the member function `size()` should be used. `sizeof` is not the right check.

```
  if(sizeof(nums1) == 0)
```

should be

```
nums1.size()==0
```

Same goes for nums2 vector as well. Another thing to note is the `output` array size is unknown at compile time and VLA is not typically supported, instead use vector here as well

```
std::vector<int> output(m+n,0); //Initialized with m+n elements with value 0
```

Comment: I modified my code and it improved a little bit. But it run into another problem. `Runtime Error Message:
AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000274 at pc 0x00000040756f bp 0x7ffe441385f0 sp 0x7ffe441385e8`